# Help with nested intervals/sequences

Tags: analysis, recurrence-relations

I really do not understand nested intervals.  For example, one of my homework problems is:
Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1+x_n}{2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =1$.
I think I might be able to do this problem if I better understood the nested interval stuff.

Edit:  I plugged in some fake numbers and let $x_0=0$ and then $x_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and the number got closer and closer to 1, but I'm not sure how to prove that.

Comment: It could be a typo on my professor's review sheet.  I actually found a couple of them.  Thanks!

Comment: On second thought I believe it is true.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
x_{n+1}&=\frac{1+x_n}2\\
\overbrace{x_{n+1}-1}^{u_{n+1}}&=\frac{(\overbrace{x_n-1}^{u_n})}2\\
u_{n+1}&=\frac{u_n}2\\
u_{n}&=\frac{u_{n-1}}2=\frac{u_{n-2}}{2^2}=\cdots=\frac{u_1}{2^{n-1}}\\
x_n-1&=\frac{x_1-1}{2^{n-1}}\\
x_n&=1+\frac{x_1-1}{2^{n-1}}\\
\lim_{n\to0}x_n&=1\qquad \blacksquare 
\end{align}$$